# Sound not working on an Intel 5 Series/3400 

Tags: 11.10, sound

lspci gives me these two devices:

```
$ lspci | grep Audio
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 05)
02:00.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc RV710/730
```

There are two devices listed in System Settings|Sound|Output:

- RV710/730 Digital Stereo (HDMI)
- Internal Audio Analog Stereo

And finally, the are not muted!

Also, when I run an application that accesses the sound card, I can see it in the Applications tab.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the new kernel update (3.0.0-13) solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am depending on a previous Launchpad q/a (last answer) [1] and suggest compiling Alsa. But instead of grabbing Realtek drivers (same as Alsa) just download latest files via alsa-project.org [2]. You need to download just alsa-driver, alsa-lib and alsa-utils packages. Pick latest ones which has 1.0.24 version. After that just compile the packages as explained there.

If you get an error about panelw library while compiling alsa-utils, just change the configure step as this:

```
./configure --with-curses=ncurses
```

[1] https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+question/93857
[2] http://alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Download

Comment: I couldn't compile alsa-driver in 11.10. I am getting this error message:


ioctl32_new.c:23:28: fatal error: linux/smp_lock.h: No such file or directory

Comment: This error occurs because of removal of BKL: http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Removing_the_Big_Kernel_Lock That means our kernel is too update for Alsa packages. With those packages we can fix somehow (dirty way) smp_lock error but there will be others. So, grab the latest snapshots here: http://www.alsa-project.org/snapshot/ Compiling is a bit tricky. First, install **patch** and **libncurses5-dev** directly. Then use this `sudo apt-get install xmlto --no-install-recommends` to install just xmlto. When compiling alsa-utils use this: `./configure --with-curses=ncurses --disable-nls`

Comment: Thanks heartsmagic for the help. I could make alsa-driver and alsa-lib. When I'm making alsa-utils, I'm getting this:

checking for snd_ctl_elem_add_enumerated... no
configure: error: No user enum control support in alsa-lib

Comment: Have you successfully installed alsa-driver and alsa-lib after compiling them? I think, this error occures because of no installation of the new packages.

Comment: Yes, I installed both. I think I did "make install" too. I'll check again.

Comment: I am asking this because I tried compiling it without installing alsa-driver and alsa-lib (just compiled) and got that error on my current system. After that I tried it on a virtual 11.10, compiled and installed every one of them without any error.

Comment: Thanks heartsmagic. I could make install all three. For the alsa-lib I was compiling the first link and that one didn't have snd_ctl_elem_add_enumerated.

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: So, sound is not working again? Did you configure as told in the launchpad bug page? I mean with `./configure --with-cards=hda-intel --with-card-options=hda-codec-realtek`

Comment: Yes. I did configure with the same options. Now when I go to the Sound Settings, in the output tab I see a "Dummy Output" and there's nothing in input tab.

Comment: I came to a dead end here. According to this comment [1] maybe you can try OSS [2]. [1] http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8844577&postcount=2 [2] https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenSound

Comment: Wait! I got this error from alsaconf: 

`/usr/sbin/alsaconf: line 929: update-modules: command not found`

Comment: I think something mixed up with installation. Was this the same before compiling Alsa or occured after you compiled it?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I solved reinstalling alsa modules
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)